# Read from file: read two lines, skip two lines

Tags: python

I want to read two lines from a file, skip the next two lines and read the next two lines and so on

```
line 1 (read)
line 2 (read)
line 3 (skip)
line 4 (skip)
line 5 (read)
line 6 (read)
...
<eof>
```

Any ideas how to do this? Thanks!

My solution:

```
            j = 2

            for i, line in enumerate(f.readlines()):
                if i in xrange(j - 2, j):
                    print line
                elif i == j:
                    j += 4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can advance the iteration of the file with [the `itertools` `consume()` recipe](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) - as it is fast (it uses `itertools` functions to ensure the iteration happens in low-level code, making the process of consuming the values very fast, and avoids using up memory by storing the consumed values):

```
from itertools import islice
import collections

def consume(iterator, n):
    "Advance the iterator n-steps ahead. If n is none, consume entirely."
    # Use functions that consume iterators at C speed.
    if n is None:
        # feed the entire iterator into a zero-length deque
        collections.deque(iterator, maxlen=0)
    else:
        # advance to the empty slice starting at position n
        next(islice(iterator, n, n), None)
```

By doing this, you can do something like:

```
with open("file.txt") as file:
    for i, line in enumerate(file, 1):
        ...
        if not i % 2:
            consume(file, 2)  # Skip 2 lines ahead.
```

We use `enumerate()` to count our progress, and skip ahead every two lines (note that `enumerate()` adds the numbers *after* the values are skipped, meaning that it doesn't count the skipped values, as wanted).

This is a good solution as it avoids any Python looping at all for the skipped values, cutting them out completely.

Answer (score 3):

Group them into pairs, and then skip every other pair, eg:

```
from itertools import izip_longest, islice

with open('somefile') as fin:
    paired = izip_longest(*[iter(fin)] * 2, fillvalue='')
    every_other = islice(paired, None, None, 2)
    for lines in every_other:
        line1, line2 = lines
        print line1, line2
```

Example output of file containing lines 1 - 9:

```
1 2
5 6
9
```

Or to iterate over them as one long sequence:

```
from itertools import chain
lines = chain.from_iterable(every_other)
for line in lines:
    # whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

```
f = open("file", "r")

i = 0
for line in f.readlines():
    if i % 4 or (i+1) % 4:
        print line
```

I.e. you anyway have to read all the lines, but just don't do an action with lines you don't want to read.

Answer (score 0):

```
counter = 0
for line in FILE:
    if counter == 0 or counter == 1:
        print line
    counter += 1

    if counter == 3:
        counter = 0
```